# Display Multiple IDs columns from table

Tags: php, mysql

At the moment I am displaying only the first ID sorted ascending.
I have to display multiple ID results, from the same table. How would I accomplish this task?

```
<?php
   $dbhost ='localhost'; 
   $dbuser =‘user’; $dbpass =‘pass’;
   $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
   if(!$conn){
       die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }
   $sql = 'SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0, 1';
   mysql_select_db('database_name’);
   $retval = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
   if(!$retval){
       die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
   }
?>

<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($retval))
    {echo "{$row[‘full_name’]}”.”
    {$row[‘telephone']}"."
    {$row[‘email’]}”;}
    mysql_close($conn); 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is change the `LIMIT 1` to whatever number you want, or just remove it. Removing it would look like:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY id ASC'
```

Comment: Yes your right Mr. hichris, although, I would like to display each ID result in separate DIVs ..   ex: <div1>id_1_result</div>  <div2>id_2_result</div>.... but they are all from the same table. If I remove the LIMIt all results will be displayed in div1.  thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

why do you have a limit if you want all the ids to be displayed?

you can use a while loop in your script

for eg:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($test)){
                                      <div id="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['id']'.</div>;
                                      }
```

which will output:

```
<div id="my id 1">my data 1</div>
<div id="my id 2">my data 2</div>
<div id="my id 3">my data 3</div>
.
. 
. 
and so on
```

---

your modified code that outputs the data in different divs

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pass" ,"database name") or die("Could not connect database");//keep it in one line and use (mysqli) instead of (mysql) because newer mysql versions donot support (mysql)
$retreive=mysqli_query($db,'SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY id');//if youre connection is in another file you need to include the connection variable before the selection line.In this case $db is the connection variable
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($retrieve))
{ the following code creates a div for each result
echo '<div class="'.$row['fullname'].'">'.$row['fullname'].'</div>';.
echo '<div class="'.$row['telephone'].'">'.$row['telephone'].'</div>';
echo '<div class="'.$row['email'].'">'.$row['email'].'</div>';
}
?>
```

tried the above code on my test server and it works

Comment: Hello Mr. Yasin, thank you for your kindness. I would like to have each ID result, from one table, displayed in different divs. for example: table_1, row_1 displays ID 1.     table_1,row_2 displays ID 2  and so on..

Comment: so just echo the divs along the with the values in the div

Comment: Please forgive me Mr. Yasin, when I echo the divs with the code below, i could only display the first ou the last results of the table:     <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($retval)){echo "{$row['fuul_name']}"."{$row['Telephone']}"."{$row['email']}";
}mysql_close($conn); ?>

Comment: I see, it seems a lot simpler.  How may I adapt your idea with the code example above(my first post)? I am trying in various ways with no success.

Comment: ok first of all you need to download the latest mysql servers or else mysqli functions may not work properly you can try xampp

Comment: Mr. Yasin, actually, I meant to do this:  <full name, telephone, email> .

Comment: was it the solution you were looking for?